# WebView: Blocked a frame with origin www.youtube.com

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I get this message when I try to play youtube videos in my WebView

> Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.youtube.com" from accessing a
>   frame with origin
>   "applewebdata://b102c2f1-19a4-4dea-bff2-b131be89929f".  The frame
>   requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed
>   has a protocol of "applewebdata". Protocols must match.

The baseUrl of my webview is currently set to `nil`.
I know I should change it to `@"http://"`, but a lot of links and stuff in the view is based on it. If I change it I get a blank screen, because the html breaks.

So I was trying to intercept the call to youtube, when the user click on the youtube link, to change the baseUrl on the fly. But this seems to be not possible. For other actions I use this function and it works well:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation request:(NSURLRequest *)request frame:(WebFrame *)frame decisionListener:(id < WebPolicyDecisionListener >)listener
```

How could I solve this issue? The videos were working correctly on previous OSX and I'm using the usual iFrame snippet to include the video.

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="{$width}" height="{$height}"
      src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{$youtubelink}?html5=1" frameborder="0">
```

**UPDATE**
I've to encode the url as workaround:

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="{$width}" height="{$height}" src="data:text/html;base64,aHR0cDovL3d3dy55b3V0dWJlLmNvbS9lbWJlZC97JHlvdXR1YmVsaW5rfT9odG1sNT0x" frameborder="0">
```

but what I get is the URL as string text in the html.

**UPDATE 2**
Using Google APIs.

```
<div id="youtubep" class="youtube-player"></div>

<script>
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);


var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
player = new YT.Player('youtubep', {
height: '390',
width: '640',
videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
events: {
'onReady': onPlayerReady
}
});
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
event.target.playVideo();
}

</script>
```

Still it is not working:

```
[Warning] Untrusted origin: applewebdata://f53223b5-2587-4c0e-9937-bf3e9b07ff92 (www-embed-player.js, line 152, x26)
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?mt=1449582813&mv=m&ms=au&source=youtube&key=yt6&clen=41094349&requiressl=yes&mm=31&mn=sn-5hnedn76&gcr=nl&initcwndbps=1451250&id=o-ALVwEvIylUeyOATePUVUFg-cbUR-qvn9AnZ9FdKuwcLH&upn=RA7SrQEDQdw&lmt=1432476385386698&ip=95.97.243.202&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cgcr%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnh%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&fexp=9407194%2C9408500%2C9408710%2C9415030%2C9416126%2C9417204%2C9417683%2C9418204%2C9419541%2C9420310%2C9420452%2C9422141%2C9422596%2C9422618%2C9423662%2C9424480&gir=yes&pl=18&dur=1343.599&sver=3&expire=1449604537&nh=IgpwcjA0LmFtczE2Kg4yMTMuNDYuMTgyLjEwNQ&mime=video%2Fmp4&itag=133&signature=4D2797CB2BE5FCFA7CB78FACD14E8423EC2013B7.329BD308AA58011A920BAEFACA0F5869C7B84FC1&ipbits=0&cpn=b5qfNKIpHmOvNtyU&alr=yes&keepalive=yes&ratebypass=yes&c=WEB&cver=html5&cmo=pf=1&range=0-3730&rn=12&playerretry=2&rbuf=0. Origin https://www.youtube.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Comment: What's happening when you try to set the `baseURL` in `decidePolicyForNavigationAction`?

Comment: Show us all your code please :)

Comment: @kabiroberai decidePolicyForNavigationAction is not called when I click on the youtube video. It's only called when I click on other elements of the html page. So I can't update baseURL on the fly.

Comment: @HannahLouisaCarney I've added it :) But as I said, it's just the normal iframe youtube code. Also, it used to work in the past (previous OSX, not sure when it stopped to work).

Comment: @kabiroberai hi sorry it has been passed a while, but any tip? Still problem unsolved...

Comment: @HannahLouisaCarney any idea?

Comment: Where is applewebdata://b102c2f1-19a4-4dea-bff2-b131be89929f  coming from? How is that getting passed in?

Comment: is this ios9 specific -- if so. It might be AppTransportSecurity

Comment: @Patrick try making an `iframe` with the source `data:text/html,<iframe src=...>`

Comment: @Daij-Djan No, OSX. Check tags

Comment: @HannahLouisaCarney I'm afraid I can't answer your question. This is what I get from the log file, I guess it's a video frame from youtube.

Comment: I use the Javascript iframe API and I'm able to play videos just fine. I do still get this same error message and I'm unable to hook into any of the javascript events.

Comment: @JeremyHicks What's your code more in detail? You just use the iFrame tag, or some javascript too? Could you share?

Comment: @kabiroberai I think I did what you suggest (see update in my question), but it load the video anymore, just displaying the url string in the template. Is maybe because this code is embedded in a xsl template?

Comment: @Patrick use a base 64 encoder to write the iframe html and put that in the data:text/html iframe

Comment: @Patrick https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=en It's all created through javascript. That guide should get you on your way.

Comment: @kabiroberai I've done it and it doesn't work. Check my question, the update code.

Comment: @Patrick huh... I was trying to access a youtube embedded iframe in my app, and came across the same error - except for the fact that my `UIWebView` does indeed have the `baseUrl` set to `https`. Sadly I don't have control over the `src`, but do tell me if my answer below works for you

Answer (score 1):

Basically no need of embedCode.

```
float width = 200.0f;
float height = 200.0f;


UIWebView *wv = [UIWebView new];
wv.frame = CGRectMake(60, 60, width, height);
wv.delegate = self;
// URL from safari address bar.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fDXWW5vX-64"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[wv loadRequest:request];

[self.view addSubview:wv];
```

and add the UIWebViewDelegate protocol to the View controller.Hope it works.

Comment: I'm not on iOS. I've specified OSX in the tags, I don't have a UIWebView.

Comment: I believe my last hope is now to embed a webView with the youtube video, inside the parent webView loading local files. However, how could I embed such view, in the exact same point as it is now embedded in the middle of the html code?

Answer (score 0):

Going the javascript route has worked well for me:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=en

I did have to add a base URL of "https://" to be able to interact with the callback events. Otherwise, they didn't appear to get fired.

Comment: I've done what you suggest, but still the video is not loading, check the error message I've added to the question.

Comment: You mentioned not being able to set the baseUrl to "https://" on your loadHTML call. Does the video work when you do that?

Comment: The idea was to find a work-around to avoid to change the Base URL to https://  by using javascript. But you just wrote in your answer that in order to make it work you needed to use as base URL "https://". So there is no real answer to my question I guess. In the question I've written: "The baseUrl of my webview is currently set to nil. I know I should change it to @"http://", but a lot of links and stuff in the view is based on it. If I change it I get a blank screen, because the html breaks."

Comment: @Patrick Is there any way you can isolate the Youtube player to its own web view and then only set the baseURL for that single web view, putting all your other content in another web view and keeping its base URL as nil?

The player still worked for me without having to set the base URL to something other than nil. I just have additional features that require me to be able to interact with the Javascript events. That part wouldn't work without setting the baseURL.

Comment: Indeed this seems to be the only solution: to use another webView for the youtube player only. However, I'm wondering i i can embed a web view inside the html code of a parent webView. Otherwise I need to change the layout of the page, and that sucks.

Comment: Why do you need to embed the webview in another webview? Can't you just have one below the first?

Comment: Because the layout of the page has the video right in the middle of the content. It's embedded in the html code.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this is the answer, but this is how I get videos to play with iframe. Maybe it will help you a bit:

```
    NSString *website = model.contentVideoURL;
    NSInteger height = self.view.frame.size.height - self.topView.frame.size.height - 70;
    NSString *embedCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<iframe width=\"100%%\" height=\"%li\" src=\"%@\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>",(long)height, website];;
    [[self webView] loadHTMLString:embedCode baseURL:nil];
```

Also try adding:

`<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>`

To your info.Plist source code

Comment: Thanks, well it's the same answer of @kabiroberai if I'm not wrong. And indeed you are using the syntax  \" for the quotes in the string (he didn't use that). But unfortunately the result is the same, a blank page, the template crashes.

Comment: Edited my question.  this is how I solved a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the `iframe` with the following:

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="{$width}" height="{$height}" src="data:text/html,<iframe src=&quot;http://www.youtube.com/embed/{$youtubelink}?html5=1&quot; width=100% height=100% frameborder=0>" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Nop. The WebView crashes with that code. (ps. the </iframe> ending tag is missing and I've tried to add it but with the same results).

Comment: @Patrick oh, sorry that I couldn't be of any help. However, I'll be sure to tell you if I manage to figure it out

Comment: Is maybe because I need to add quotes to the attributes in the src string as well? I'm not sure about the syntax but something like height=/"100%/" for example?

Comment: @Patrick I don't think so. When I tested this in Safari, the code worked perfectly

Comment: @Patrick are you getting an error with this code though? If so, what is it?

Comment: i can't access to the Console log because the webpage is blank and I can't even right click on it to open the inspector

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97389/discussion-between-kabiroberai-and-patrick).

Comment: I start to think, the only solution is to embed a webView inside the parent webView